# SaveAsCopy to folder with name from range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use a code that saves a copy of the excel workbook i am using to a specific folder.

This below is what I have but i don't seem to get any copies saved.

The Value I have in **`"G4"`** is the name I would like the copy to be printed as.

Does anyone have any ideas about what could be the problem?

I am still having problems learning this VBA stuff=) Its hard for a new programmer.

```
Sub SparatillFolder()
Dim strFilename, strPathname, strDefpath As String
On Error Resume Next ' If directory exist goto next line


strFilename = sheets("Graf").Range("G4").Value 'New file name
strDefpath = "\\C:"MYFOLDER"  \dxakmh\Desktop\TestMiljö\Prognosverktyg\Sektionsfil\Gruppfiler\NyStruktur" 'Default path name
If IsEmpty(strFilename) Then Exit Sub

MkDir strDefpath
strPathname = strFilename 'filename

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=strFilename & ".xlsm"
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance dear SO.

Comment: Your `strDefpath` is incorrect

Comment: Side notes: I hardly recommend (1) avoid using `On Error Resume Next` because it just mutes errors and it is very bad practice: [VBA Good Practices - Error Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5411/error-handling). (2) For every variable its type must be specified because `Dim strFilename, strPathname, strDefpath As String` leaves the first 2 as `Variant` only the last one is a `String` use: `Dim strFilename As String, strPathname As String, strDefpath As String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strDefpath` should be `strDefpath = "C:\dxakmh\Desktop\TestMiljö\Prognosverktyg\Sektionsfil\Gruppfiler\NyStruktur"`

also use **`.Text`** Example `Sheets("Graf").Range("G4").Text`

```
Option Explicit
Sub SparatillFolder()
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim strDefpath As String

    'New file name
    strFilename = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graf").Range("G4").Text
    strDefpath = "C:\dxakmh\Desktop\TestMiljö\Prognosverktyg\Sektionsfil\Gruppfiler\NyStruktur"

    If IsEmpty(strFilename) Then Exit Sub

    If Len(Dir(strDefpath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir strDefpath

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=strDefpath & "\" & strFilename & ".xlsm"
End Sub
```

> ***[Range.Text Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)***
>   *Returns or sets the text for the specified object. Read-only String.*

Comment: Side Note: For every variable its type must be specified because `Dim strFilename, strPathname, strDefpath As String` leaves the first 2 as `Variant` only the last one is a `String` use: `Dim strFilename As String, strPathname As String, strDefpath As String` instead.

Comment: @Peh Your right, I totally forgot about it, I think its time for me to catch coffee break :-)